# C4.5 algorithm with unbounded attributes

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Current implementation of C4.5 in VFDT (http://www.cs.washington.edu/dm/vfml/vfdt.html) or for that matter any other implementation uses the C4.5 format of files for providing inputs for constructing the decision tree. According to this the attributes can have the following formats:

**continuous**
    If the attribute has a continuous value.

**discrete** 
    The word 'discrete' followed by an integer which indicates how many values the attribute can take.

**list of identifiers**
    This is a discrete attribute with the values enumerated (this is the prefered method for discrete attributes).  The identifiers should be separated by commas.

**ignore**
    means the attribute should be ignored - it won't be used.

Does anybody know how we can specify discrete valued attributes whose complete set of possible values is too large to list down?

For example "IP-Address" attribute can have Math.Pow(255,4) possible discrete values;
"QueryString" attribute can have infinite number of possible values ... etc.

Can the C4.5 algorithm handle the case where the attribute has say 100,000 discrete distinct values, OR where the exact bound is not known, but only an approximation is known?

Thanks.

Comment: C4.5 is a pretty old algorithm (and SVMs are showing their age too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual choice is to enumerate all the values of a discrete feature that occur in your training set. Since the algorithm can never gather enough statistics for values that are not seen during training, those would be ignored no matter how you'd implement them.

Mind you, it's quite hard to gather statistics for such features anyway, so you might want to think about different representations. In particular, multi-word strings of text can be tokenized and treated as [bags of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model).

Comment: Thanks @larsmans for your response. Please see below for a detailed response.

Comment: The bag of words approach is definitely useful when the number of features is huge. So I could consider each IP or each word in the query string as a separate feature. With this approach the SVM algorithm seems more accurate than C4.5. Some studies have shown that this is indeed the case > (Pang, Bo, Lillian Lee and Shivakumar Vaithyanathan. 2002. Thumbs up? > Sentiment classification using machine learning techniques. In > Proceedings of the 2002 Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural > Language Processing (EMNLP), pages 79-86.).

Comment: So I guess the answer to the question is "not possible, choose another algorithm like SVM". I would still like to know if someone knows of perfect solution to this scenario (the best algorithm that can handle features with millions of possible discrete values). Thanks.

Comment: @whywhywhy: depends strongly on the problem, but I personally always start a machine learning experiment with a linear model (linear SVM or logistic regression), esp. when handling data with large numbers of features. Those models tend to scale up gracefully.